# Static content deploy error after upgrading magento 2.4.3-p1 to 2.4.4

Tags: magento-upgrade, static-content-deploy, magento2.4.4

***php ver 8.1***

> Error happened during deploy process: Deprecated Functionality:
> pathinfo(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($path) of type string is
> deprecated in
> /vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/PreProcessor/FileNameResolver.php
> on line 45

*if any person face this error and solved please help to solved this error*

Comment: can you check with  public function resolve($fileName)
to
public function resolve($fileName = null )

Comment: Related question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/361149/proper-way-to-fix-deprecated-functionality-pathinfo-passing-null-to-paramete/362567#362567

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution: –**

Go to the parent directory of your theme, it must be in

**vendor/magento/theme-magento-blank** or **theme-magneto-luma/** then **web/images**, copy **logo.svg** and put this in your theme directory

> app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[theme]/web/images

The problem was we should put the logo.svg image file in our theme:

> app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[theme]/web/images/logo.svg

In Magento 2.4.4, Child themes need to have a logo.svg file.

Once you copied logo.svg from parent to your theme. Do the following :

```
Remove the files and folders present inside pub/static/frontend
Remove the files and folders present inside var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend
Run the deploy command  – php bin/magento s:s:d -f
```

Answer (score 10):

Make sure that logo of theme is here app/design/frontend/[Your Vendor]/[Theme Name]/web/images/logo.svg

It is necessary. But I guess it is bug of Magento 2 with PHP 8.1

Comment: Thanks. This isn't quite correct, but took me to the bug report [https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/35293]. Adding web/images/logo.png to all child themes worked for me.

Comment: This works. thank you! saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 7):

The issue has been caused because **your custom theme doesn't have a preview image**, then PHP 8.1 throws that error due to Magento core logic.

Fix that by adding an image to your custom theme.

For example: `app/design/frontend/[Your Vendor]/[Theme Name]/web/images/logo.svg`

[image: Magento 2 custom theme image]

Comment: Hello @Rafael Corrêa Gomes, Thanks for your reply but i already adding an image to my custom theme Even then the error comes

Answer (score 2):

Worked for me without modifying the vendor/magento/framework/App/Utility/Files.php.

After modifying theme.xml file and adding a preview image. i also added a logo.svg in theme folder/web/images/logo.svg and it worked

```
    if (!$files) {
                echo $themePackage->getVendor(). '' .  $themePackage->getName().'<br>';
                $result[] = [
                    $themeArea,
                    $themePackage->getVendor() . '/' . $themePackage->getName(),
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null
                ];
            }
```

Just add the echo and u can see which theme is creating the issue

Answer (score 1):

**Backtrace the error**

Add the following code in `/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/PreProcessor/FileNameResolver.php` above line 45

```
if ($fileName === null) { 
    debug_print_backtrace(2); 
    die;
}
```

For me, the backtrace output was something like this:

```
#0 vendor/magento/module-deploy/Collector/Collector.php(97): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\PreProcessor\FileNameResolver->resolve(NULL)
#1 vendor/magento/module-deploy/Package/PackagePool.php(183): Magento\Deploy\Collector\Collector->collect()
#2 vendor/magento/module-deploy/Package/PackagePool.php(117): Magento\Deploy\Package\PackagePool->collect()
#3 vendor/magento/module-deploy/Strategy/QuickDeploy.php(54): Magento\Deploy\Package\PackagePool->getPackagesForDeployment(Array)
```

I had to create the following patch to fix the error:

```
--- a/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Collector/Collector.php
+++ b/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Collector/Collector.php
@@ -90,7 +90,7 @@
         foreach ($this->sourcePool->getAll() as $source) {
             $files = $source->get();
             foreach ($files as $file) {
-                if ($file->getModule() && !$this->moduleManager->isEnabled($file->getModule())) {
+                if ($file->getModule() && !$this->moduleManager->isEnabled($file->getModule()) || is_null($file->getFileName())) {
                     continue;
                 }
                 $file->setDeployedFileName($this->fileNameResolver->resolve($file->getFileName()));
```

Comment: Patch worked perfectly, Thanks. 
for people wondering how to use a patch just 
nano patch_for_245.patch mylook-upgraded-245
and paste above code there and apply with
    patch -p1 < patch_for_245.patch

Answer (score 0):

If the theme is Porto, the following may help:

```
rm -R ./app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child
```

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted theme then getting the same error. When i running the content deploy command.

> Deploy using quick strategy
> Error happened during deploy process: Deprecated Functionality:
> pathinfo(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($path) of type string is
> deprecated in
> /vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/PreProcessor/FileNameResolver.php
> on line 42

So for this i have added this solution and working fine.

Before

> $extension = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

After

> $extension = pathinfo($fileName ?? "", PATHINFO_EXTENSION);