# proper way to fix Deprecated Functionality: pathinfo(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($path) of type string is deprecated in

Tags: magento2.4.4

guys i want proper way to fix Deprecated Functionality: pathinfo(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($path) of type string is deprecated in vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/PreProcessor/FileNameResolver.phpline 44

things to be in mind:

1. cant change in magento core files.
   2)logo/preview image files already added in custom theme.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Related question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/355665/static-content-deploy-error-after-upgrading-magento-2-4-3-p1-to-2-4-4/362566#362566

Answer (score 1):

I have written preference for this in custom module:
**create di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\View\Asset\PreProcessor\FileNameResolver" type="Custom\CorePatch\View\Asset\PreProcessor\FileNameResolver" />
    
</config>
```

**create FileNameResolver in respective folder as mentioned:**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Custom\CorePatch\View\Asset\PreProcessor;

/**
 * Class FileNameResolver
 *
 * @package Magento\Framework\View\Asset\PreProcessor
 */
class FileNameResolver extends \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\PreProcessor\FileNameResolver
{
    /**
     * @var AlternativeSource[]
     */
    private $alternativeSources;

    /**
     * FileNameResolver constructor.
     * @param array $alternativeSources
     * @internal param AlternativeSource $alternativeSource
     */
    public function __construct(array $alternativeSources = [])
    {
        $this->alternativeSources = array_map(
            function (\Magento\Framework\View\Asset\PreProcessor\AlternativeSourceInterface $alternativeSource) {
                return $alternativeSource;
            },
            $alternativeSources
        );
    }

    /**
     * Resolve filename
     *
     * @param string $fileName
     * @return string
     */
    public function resolve($fileName)
    {
        $compiledFile = $fileName;
        $extension = pathinfo((string)$fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        foreach ($this->alternativeSources as $name => $alternative) {
            if ($alternative->isExtensionSupported($extension)
                && strpos(basename($fileName), '_') !== 0
            ) {
                $compiledFile = substr($fileName, 0, strlen($fileName) - strlen($extension) - 1);
                $compiledFile = $compiledFile . '.' . $name;
            }
        }
        return $compiledFile;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the bug in Magento 2.4.4 & 2.4.5

So you need to apply below patch to fix the issue

Create a folder name **patches** in root of your Magento then create a file name **CustomThemeLogo.patch** in that folder

**patches/CustomThemeLogo.patch**

Add below code and save the file:

```
diff --git a/App/Utility/Files.php b/App/Utility/Files.php
index 00c1e89..b872c08 100644
--- a/App/Utility/Files.php
+++ b/App/Utility/Files.php
@@ -959,10 +959,10 @@
                     $result[] = [
                         $themeArea,
                         $themePackage->getVendor() . '/' . $themePackage->getName(),
-                        null,
-                        null,
-                        null,
-                        null
+                        '',
+                        '',
+                        '',
+                        ''
                     ];
                 }
             }
```

Now open your **composer.json** file and add patch file location:

Add below code in **extra**

```
 "extra": {
    "magento-force": "override",
    "composer-exit-on-patch-failure": true,
    "patches": { 
        "magento/framework": { 
            "Patch for Magento issue with custom theme logo": "patches/CustomThemeLogo.patch" 
        }
    }
}
```

Now run **composer install** or **composer update** command as required

And other commands

It will resolve your issue

Thanks

Comment: i dont think so this is better way to do this, creating a patch and force magento to override utility files is not success for me

Answer (score 0):

**Backtrace the error**

Add the following code in `/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/PreProcessor/FileNameResolver.php` above line 45

```
if ($fileName === null) { 
    debug_print_backtrace(2); 
    die;
}
```

For me, the backtrace putout was something like this:

```
#0 vendor/magento/module-deploy/Collector/Collector.php(97): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\PreProcessor\FileNameResolver->resolve(NULL)
#1 vendor/magento/module-deploy/Package/PackagePool.php(183): Magento\Deploy\Collector\Collector->collect()
#2 vendor/magento/module-deploy/Package/PackagePool.php(117): Magento\Deploy\Package\PackagePool->collect()
#3 vendor/magento/module-deploy/Strategy/QuickDeploy.php(54): Magento\Deploy\Package\PackagePool->getPackagesForDeployment(Array)
```

I had to create the following patch to fix the error:

```
--- a/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Collector/Collector.php
+++ b/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Collector/Collector.php
@@ -90,7 +90,7 @@
         foreach ($this->sourcePool->getAll() as $source) {
             $files = $source->get();
             foreach ($files as $file) {
-                if ($file->getModule() && !$this->moduleManager->isEnabled($file->getModule())) {
+                if ($file->getModule() && !$this->moduleManager->isEnabled($file->getModule()) || is_null($file->getFileName())) {
                     continue;
                 }
                 $file->setDeployedFileName($this->fileNameResolver->resolve($file->getFileName()));
```

Answer (score -2):

If the theme is **Porto**, the following may help:

```
rm -R ./app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child
```